# Using Scout templating in themosis framework version 1.2

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I was hoping someone could help me with my understanding when using the @sectoin and @yield commands inside a themosis 1.2 scout template.

Basically I have a view "/views/my-page.scout.php" with some basic html markup:

```
@include('includes.header')
  <div> some content </div>
  @yield('extra-content')
@include('includes.footer')
enter code here
```

Then inside of another file located in "views/extras/extra-content.scout.php" I have the following:

```
@section('extra-content')
  <div>Some extra content</div>
@stop
```

Im not sure why my @yield is not working, I know I could just use @include but I wanted to get a better understanding of using @yield. Ive checked out the [laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#template-inheritance) and [themosis](https://framework.themosis.com/docs/1.2/scout/) documentation but im still confused.

Any help would be most appreciated. :)

---

File location: **/views/extras/extra-content.scout.php**

File name: **extra-content.scout.php**

File Contents:

```
@section('extra-content')
  <div>Some extra content</div>
@stop
```

---

File location: **/views/my-page.scout.php**

File name: **my-page.scout.php**

File Contents:

```
@include('includes.header')
  <div> some content </div>
  @yield('extra-content')
@include('includes.footer')
```

Comment: You know you've written `@yeild` in your code, right...?

Comment: lol sorry that was a typo but in my code its correct "yield"

Comment: is the file `views/extras/extra-content.scout.php` used in your view somehow? just a question ;)

Comment: @okante, correct that's my folder structure for the file I want to yield

Comment: @WhiteRabbit, can you show where this `extra-content.scout` is used? to yield this value, you should haved included this file somewhere.

Comment: @okante, Ive updated my initial question :)

Comment: @WhiteRabbit, so I will post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File : my-page.scout.php

```
@include('includes.header')

@include('extras.extra-content')
  <div> some content </div>
  @yield('extra-content')
{{-- or include here @include('extras.extra-content') --}}
{{-- or include here @include('extras.extra-content') --}}
@include('includes.footer')
```

the file `extra-content` should be included explicitily in this file or any file it's extending/including.

yield will just store the content in a variable with will be available in this file. 
In your use case, including may be the best way, because your file contains only that section. imagine a extra-content file where you will output some content **and** handle 'extra-content` variable

section content will always be placed where you yield it.

this code

```
@section('my-content')
i want to place to place this content somewhere
@stop
```

will be interpreted as:

```
$sections['my-content'] = 'i want to place to place this content somewhere';
```

and

```
yield('my-content');
```

is intepreted as

```
echo isset($sections['my-content']) ? $section['my-content']:'';
```

Edit imagine your file extra-content where you define the section doesn't contains only the section definition:

File: extra-content

```
@section('my-content')
this is yielded content displayed where you use yield('my-content')
@stop
<p> this will be displayed where the file is included</p>
```

Comment: I kind of understand what you staying, But then if thats the case then whats the use of using @yield?

From the laravel documentation they state:

`The @section directive, as the name implies, defines a section of content, while the @yield directive is used to display the contents of a given section.`

Comment: Ok I see what you mean now. So in essence I need to have the `@section` and the `@yield` in the same file and they can't be external files?

So this will only work when referencing the `@extends('layouts.app')`

Comment: no, they may be in different files as in your example. try to take my `extra-content` and include it at the top (before includes.header) of your `my-page` you will see how things work

Comment: I see now how its meant to be used along with the `@include` command :). Thank you for helping me understand it better.